# What kind of lighting setup is this?

Tags: video, lighting

I'm looking to understand how this person did their lighting setups, what kind of filters they used, and angle of view (35mm equivalent focal length).

From what I can see, there is a ring light and two flolights. Are those the only 3 lights?

What kind of filter did they use to achieve the ultra soft skin tones?

What kind of focal length (35mm equivalent) are they using for his field of view?
[image: girl]

In the meantime, I found more pictures of the panels in question. Can anyone identify make and model?

[image: Lights1][image: Lights2]

Comment: Could you post a link to the video/image source? Maybe metadata can reveal something about the lens.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that the creator used a ring light, as you would definitely see the reflection of it in her eyes. The lights she used look like your regular Kinoflo or Kobalt. You could use frost, also called white diffusion in front of it to give softer light, but I don't think she used that either. Remember: The bigger the light source, the softer the light (and shadow). Kinoflos are very very big, and especially 4-Banks (flos with 4 tubes of light) give out very soft light on their own, which is why I assume she opted for this specific light.

Technically, her head is kind of disappearing into the dark tv-screen, since the hair and the display have a very similar color. To prevent this, you would usually set up a light on the opposite end of where your keylight points at. This way, you will have a nice bright edge around the back of the head, separating her from the background a bit more.

As so the lens it's very hard to tell, you'd have to go into pftrack and manually track the leading lines etc. However I assume that it's a lens way below 50mm, probably at about 20-25.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they didn't have a lot of room to play with, so two kinos, mounted vertically at 45° left & right. Quite close in to make it as broad as possible [for which I'd have used them horizontally ;)
I'd also have put diffuser gels right across the barn doors at their widest to try spread it still further.
The end result for such a potentially soft-light setup seems to have come out a bit hard-edged, the shadows in her hair etc. It's also all a bit shiny on her face.

Also, as mentioned , getting a light in back would have helped separation from the TV.

This and the fact they've got one of the kinos reflecting in the TV is what makes me think they didn't have enough room to work & also that they only had those two lights to work with.

As they've used old-fashioned fluorescent tube kinos rather than modern temperature-controllable ones, I'm guessing they mis-judged the light temperature, so the shot has come out quite a way to the magenta side. I can only guess they'd set up for "fluorescent" which doesn't work for standard tube kinos, as they actually qualify as "daylight".

Lens, I can't come up with any better guess than Florian - it's something short. A bigger giveaway would be if they'd gone for a two-shot [or even group shot] so you could see how the edges of frame were affected. With just a sofa & TV in background there's not a lot to judge from. Big nose, little ears [or in this case, big head, little shoulders] is definitely in evidence, but there's not enough for me to guess in a still without knowing what the presenter looks like in real life, or see her in motion on video.

crop/zoom - 2 kinos in eye & hard edge on face

[image]